# How to verify old password with Keycloak Admin Java API?

Tags: java, spring, security, spring-boot, keycloak

I have application which uses Keycloak 3.1.x, the application is using following dependency to interact with Keycloak remotely:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
    <artifactId>keycloak-admin-client</artifactId>
    <version>3.4.1.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

The application is using Spring Boot and in Controller we are getting two parameters:

1. old password
2. new password

Now on the backend we have to validate if the old password matches with the one stored in Keycloak and then eventually apply the new password.

I know that there is the endpoint `/auth/admin/{realm}/account` which allowes the user to change his password, yet I need that functionality on the backend.

The dependency uses RestClient under the hood and from what I found in https://issues.jboss.org/browse/KEYCLOAK-943, the Keycloak does not provide REST API for the `account` console.

Does anybody know if it is possible to validate the old password from the Keycloak Admin API?

**EDIT:**

Maybe there is a way of getting user's old password and trying to get the new token? If fails, then that would be sign that old password is wrong.

Comment: actually this is the jboss jira task you're looking for [https://issues.jboss.org/browse/KEYCLOAK-7103?workflowName=GIT+Pull+Request+workflow+&stepId=6] unfortunately they didn't respond to it properly

Comment: @DevDio, i have the exact same issue. Any update on this?

Comment: Now it is 2020 and I have the same question. Do we now have a solution for  this?

Comment: Now it is 2021 and I have the same question. Do we now have a solution for this?

Comment: Now it is 2022 and I have the same question. Do we now have a solution for this?

Comment: Resource servers should just not have access to users credentials and it should not store it in database. **User credentials is the sole responsibility of the authorization server** and only it should ever access it (not the frontend, not the resource server(s) an not the client(s)). The only exception to that rule is a client in client-credentials flow, where the client knows its own password. If you want special rules for new password, this should be enforced by Keycloak.

Answer (score 0):

There is no api method, but you can verify password by getting request for token on realms/{realm}/protocol/openid-connect/token

Comment: This solution would work. But if you has already enabled 2FA, then it's not possible to get a token for given user.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
            <artifactId>keycloak-authz-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

You can use this one from here : https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/authorization_services/

It states there that you can do this

```
AuthzClient authzClient = AuthzClient.create();
AuthorizationRequest request = new AuthorizationRequest();
AuthorizationResponse response = authzClient.authorization("alice", "alice").authorize(request);
String rpt = response.getToken();
System.out.println("You got an RPT: " + rpt);
```

but for me instead of AuthorizationRequest, you can just check if there's an accesstoken using the credentials

```
     AccessTokenResponse response =  authzClient.obtainAccessToken(emailAddress, password);
  String responseToken = response.getToken();
```

This returns an Unauthorized Exception if the password's incorrect.